# setTimeout with Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime, settimeout

I'm creating a timeout based on user input, with the input format being: `1min` or `2h`, and deciding if it's a minute or an hour via the following code;

```
if (duration.includes("h", 1)) {
  /* If the collectedDuration includes "h" in it,
  parse the string into an integer and multiply it with an hour in miliseconds */
  const intDuration = parseInt(duration, 10);
  const parsedDuration = intDuration * 3600000;
  // Create the timer with setTimeout where parsedDuration is the delay
  createTimer(item, parsedDuration);
} else if (duration.includes("m", 1)) {
  const intDuration = parseInt(duration, 10);
  const parsedDuration = intDuration * 60000;
  createTimer(item, parsedDuration);
}
```

What I want to do: Figure out how much time is left until setTimeout completes at any given time before it does. For example: Timer is created for 1 hour and 15 minutes later, I use a command to display the time left which would be 45 minutes.

I tried the convertion method found [here](http://sstut.com/javascript/convert-hours-minutes-seconds-to-milliseconds.php) but that is static; it only converts base miliseconds to hours. I need something dynamic.

I have also tried doing it with Date objects but failed. How can I go on about it?

Comment: Do you need a label to show how much is remaining ?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet [mcve]  where we can reproduce and understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: ^^ Help us help you

Comment: Apologies. This is for a Discord bot and the code is rather lenghty. This is a snippet from a code that creates a giveaway for a duration. What I want to do is, after the timer is created with ``setTimeout``, use a command that displays how much time is left for the giveaway to conclude.

The whole code for this command can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/mbacalan/AureneBot/blob/master/commands/giveaway.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with vanilla `setTimeout`. You'll have to wrap it:

```
class Timeout {
  // this is a pretty thin wrapper over setTimeout
  constructor (f, n, ...args) {
    this._start = Date.now() + n; // when it will start
    this._handle = setTimeout(f, n, ...args);
  }

  // easy cancel
  cancel () {
    clearTimeout(this._handle);
  }

  // projected start time - current time
  get timeLeft () {
    return this._start - Date.now();
  }
}
```

I wish they'd provided an OO interface for timeouts/intervals in the first place. Usage:

```
const timeout = new Timeout(console.log, 2000, 'foo', 'bar');
setTimeout(() => console.log(timeout.timeLeft), 1000);
```

Should print something like

```
1000
foo bar
```

Over the course of a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is incomplete, more of a suggestion.

You said you failed attempting to do what you need using the Date object, consider whatever that method was using the momentjs library.  Moment makes modifying Date considerably easier than converting to epoch then adding/subtracting ms.

https://momentjs.com/

You can do stuff like:

```
 var x = moment(); // sets x to now
 x.subtract(10, 'minute'); // subtracts 10 minutes
 console.log(x.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')); // see what you have now
```