# React native typescript use correct setTimeout type

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I'm trying to workout what the correct typescript tsconfig I need to apply to get the correct types for the standard library in the react native context. Specifically my issue is with setTimeout has a return typeof `NodeJS.Timeout`.

I'm using the [default tsconfig from the official react-native typescript template](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/blob/main/template/tsconfig.json).

As a follow up, where are the types of react-native VM documented? It's obviously different to nodejs and the browser. I'm not using Hermes, but maybe there are up to date types for that? What is the non-Hermes react-native JS context called?

The current hack workaround is to do the following

```
let timeout: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
// ...
timeout = setTimeout(log, 5000)
```

`tsconifg.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es2017"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-native",                    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true,                           /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    "isolatedModules": true,                  /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    "skipLibCheck": false,                    /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true                 /* Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `ReturnType<setTimeout>` will work regardless of platform.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith yeah that's what I'm doing but it's a hack!

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hack, that utility type is in the TS standard type library for a reason. YMMV.

Comment: The hack is not the utility type. The hack is that the variable is still not a number

Comment: Yes, although arguably [it shouldn't ever have been in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120691/3757232), it should have been a pauseable resumeable OO interface *describing* an action on an interval.

Comment: That's a tc39 proposal, what's that got to do with linting?

Comment: You didn't mention linting in your original question so I'm not sure where that came it? And nobody is going to propose that to the TC39, that ship set sail in 1995. I'm just dreaming/nitpicking with the benefit of 25 years of hindsight.

Comment: Yeah fair! I say linting because TS transpiles down to JS. The utility of typescript types boil down to linting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238601/discussion-between-david-adler-and-jared-smith).

Comment: The non-hermes javascript engine is [JavascriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore?language=objc)